# How to set properties for post while posting news feed using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am trying to set properties of post. And I am posting news feed using curl.

I am setting properties like this but it is not working.

```
$message = 'Message 1';
$caption = 'Caption 1';
$media["properties"] = array('category' => array( 'text' => 'humor', 'href' => 'http://www.icanhascheezburger.com/category/humor'));
$media["media"] = array("type" => "image", "src"=> $imageUrl , "href"=>$link);
$attachment = array ('name' => $caption,
             'link' => $appUrl ,
             'caption' => 'Test Caption',
             'description' => $message,
             'attachment' =>  $media
            );
```

Feed is getting published, but properties are not coming.

Please suggest me to how I should set the properties.

Comment: Docs seys you can't. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: @haynar Please do not add comments in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Tested with Graph API Explorer:

```
POST /me/feed
properties  {"name" : {"text":"abc", "href":"http://www.google.com"}, "value" : {"text":"cde", "href":"http://www.google.com"}}
```

and etc filed.

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need just to [json_encode()](http://uk.php.net/json_encode) your properties array, don't need to [urldecode()](http://uk.php.net/urldecode) it.

Just this code:

```
$attachment = array('properties' => json_encode($properties));
```

I hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

First urldecode every link you include in the attachment and also json_encode the properties before setting it in the attachment.

```
$properties = array("Title" => array('text' => "Some Text", 'href' => urldecode($link)));

$attachment = array ('properties' => json_encode($properties))
```